# Python threads and global vars

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

Say I have the following function in a module called "firstModule.py":

```
def calculate():
  # addCount value here should be used from the mainModule
   a=random.randint(0,5) + addCount
```

Now I have a different module called "secondModule.py":

```
def calculate():
  # addCount value here too should be used from the mainModule
   a=random.randint(10,20) + addCount
```

I am running a module called "mainModule.py" which has the following (notice the global "addCount" var):

```
import firstModule
import secondModule

addCount=0

Class MyThread(Thread):
  def __init__(self,name):
      Thread.__init__(self)
      self.name=name

   def run(self):
      global addCount
      if self.name=="firstModule":
         firstModule.calculate()
      if self.name=="secondModule":
         secondModule.calculate()

def main():
   the1=MyThread("firstModule");
   the2=MyThread("secondModule");
   the1.start()
   the2.start()
   the1.join()
   the2.join()

  # This part doesn't work:
   print firstModule.a
   print secondModule.a
```

Basically I want the "addCount" value in both modules to be the one from "mainModule". After that, when the threads are finished, I want to print the value
 of "a" in both of them. The example above doesn't work. I was wondering how can I fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Pass 'addCount' to the function 'calculate', return the value of 'a' in 'calculate', and assign it to a new attribute in MyThread instance.

```
def calculate(addCount):
    a = random.randint(0, 5) + addCount
    return a
```

Answer (score 2):

Modules in python are singletons, so you can put your global variables in module globalModule.py and have both firstModule, secondModule, and mainModule `import globalModule` and they will all access the same addCount.

However, in general it's a bad practice for threads to have a global state.

This will never work:

print firstModule.a
   print secondModule.a

because in here:

```
def calculate():
   # addCount value here should be used from the mainModule
   a=random.randint(0,5) + addCount
```

`a` is a local variable to the function `calculate`.

If you really want to write `a` as a module-level variable, add global declaration:

```
def calculate():
   # addCount value here should be used from the mainModule
   global a
   a=random.randint(0,5) + addCount
```